# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null -> in Firefox. Works fine in Chorme & Safari

Tags: javascript, html, import, module, getelementbyid

I've seen a lot of questions about this and I think I scanned through almost all of them but haven't found a solution for my problem yet.

As I mention in the title, Firefox return this exception **TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null** while Chrome and Safari work just fine.

```js
// main.js:

import {
  hideNavbar
} from './components/hide-navbar-onscroll.js';
import {
  displayCookieNotice
} from './components/hide-cookie-notice.js';
import {
  active
} from './components/active-menu.js';
import {
  insertNews
} from './components/insert-news.js';

window.onscroll = hideNavbar;
displayCookieNotice();
active();
insertNews();
```

```js
// components/hide-cookie-notice.js:

const displayCookieNotice = function(event) {
  document.getElementById('cookie-notice').style.bottom = "0";
  document.getElementById('cookie-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('cookie-notice').style.bottom = "-64px";
  })
}

export {
  displayCookieNotice
};
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<head>
  <!--- ... --->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    <!--- ... --->
    $.get("common/cookie-notice.html", function(data) {
      $("#cookie-notice-placeholder").replaceWith(data);
    });
  </script>
  <div>
    <!--- ... --->
    <div id="cookie-notice-placeholder">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="module" src="js/main.js">
  </script>
</body>
```

```html
<!-- common/cookie-notice.html -->

<div id="cookie-notice">
  <div class="cookie-text-box text-bright">
    <div class="cookie-text">
      <p class="margin-between">Diese Site verwendet Cookies</p>
      <p class="margin-between"><a href="/datenschutz" target="blank" class="font-yant text-bright">Datenschutz</a></p>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-small" id="cookie-button">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As pointed in other similar questions, this seems to have to do with the fact that when doing document.getElementById the page might not be fully loaded yet and the element isn't found. For that reason I already moved script.js to the end of the page right before  but this had no effect.
Also I tried to add 'defer' to the  loading the main.js module ... no effect either.

Anyone has ideas how to fix that?

Comment: So you are referencing the element before it exists on the page

Comment: Here is the Error Message in the Console:

Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    displayCookieNotcie http://localhost:3000/js/components/hide-cookie-notice.js:2
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:7
hide-cookie-notice.js:2:12
    displayCookieNotcie http://localhost:3000/js/components/hide-cookie-notice.js:2
    <anonym> http://localhost:3000/js/main.js:7
    InnerModuleEvaluation self-hosted:2382
    evaluation self-hosted:2333

Comment: Trigger the code that does the initialization after the Ajax code runs.

Comment: You need to trigger the code `$.get("common/cookie-notice.html", function(data) {
      $("#cookie-notice-placeholder").replaceWith(data); /* here */
    });`

Comment: `$.get("common/cookie-notice.html", function(data) {
        $("#cookie-notice-placeholder").replaceWith(data); 
        displayCookieNotice();
      });`
still doesn't work